# CSS bootstrap elements not aligning horizontal well

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-float

I have a form with `Bootstrap` CSS.

The CSS is `left-to-right` but I need the form fields to be `right-to-left`. So I added a class that contains `float: right` to each of the forms.

All the fields are supposed to float one next to each other, but the problem is that some of the lines break in the middle, as can be seen in the image below.

I have searched and couldn't find what is causing the line to break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parent element with class "row" for the set of `input` elements that you want to be in one line.

Comment: eventually I added `row` for every line thogh bootstrap sopouse to work the way I used  it. anyway your answer gave me inspiration

Answer (score 0):

You set class - "col-md-4" so, line is divided into 3 elements with 33% of width. If u want 4 elements in line u have to set "col-md-3", then u will have 12/3 = 4, 4 elements with 25% width :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But all the div's share the same `col-md-4` class. there are no divs with `col-md-3` class in my page.

Comment: I see that.
Look at that code, boostrap is working like this 
row = 12
col-md-<number> is 12/<number> = you get numbers of elements you can set in a row

So if u want 4 elements in row set col-md-3